# Создание объекта Gson кладет весь проект

Tags: java, json, tomcat, gson

Есть проект: сервлеты + Tomcat.
Есть написанный класс Tweet и синглтон класс TweetCollection хранящий в листе объекты Tweet.
Хочу сделать сериализацию в json используя библиотеку Gson обоих классов. Но почему-то при инициализации объекта Gson проект падает. Вот это подключаю к проекту:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Вот на такой строке обычно заканчивается работа

```
System.out.println("tweet is " + new Gson().toJson(tweet));
```

метод `toString()` переписан и с ним все в порядке, выдает обычную строку.

Не совсем точно выразился, когда написал что ложится проект. 
Например падающий в методе doGet. получаю такой выход:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    b {
      color: white;
      background-color: #525D76;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: black;
    }
    
    .line {
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #525D76;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error</h1>
  <hr class="line" />
  <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
  <p><b>Message</b> Servlet execution threw an exception</p>
  <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
  </p>
  <p><b>Exception</b></p>
  <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre>
  <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
  <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com&#47;google&#47;gson&#47;Gson
 com.cryztal.servlets.TweetsServlet.doGet(TweetsServlet.java:27)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre>
  <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
  <hr class="line" />
  <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.29</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот такой лог:

```
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: а что значит ложиться? что в консоли?

Comment: Ну приведите, какое сообщение вы получаете, когда проект падает.

Comment: Ошибки в Log ни о чем не говорят, похоже больше на следствие, а не на причину. А вот в самой странице ошибка NoClassDefFoundError - она возникает, когда класс не может загрузиться во время выполнения кода. Что-то не так с библиотекой, она либо не доступна по какой-то причине, либо не попала в сборку для сервера. Возможно [этот ответ поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even).

Comment: Добавьте класс Tweet

Comment: Я могу добавить класс Tweet, но тут действительно проблема должна быть в подключении Gson. Я там добавил зависимости из Maven. Вроде бы они нормальные

Comment: Проблема не в классе Tweet даже потому, что код перестает работать если просто объявить объект класса Gson.

Comment: для начала в сообщениях консоли, которые вы выложили, нет ничего о Gson. а еще меня смутила вот эта строка в описании проблемы "метод toString() переписан и с ним все в порядке". зачем вам метод toString() и какое он имеет отношение к Gson?

Comment: Я просто привел пример строки, на которой ошибка происходит. Там вывод экземпляра Tweet. 
Но суть в том, что я вставил строку  "Gson json = new Gson();" и теперь все останавливается на ней.